# Fatal error with webkit2gtk-4.0 (webkit2.h)

Tags: programming

I use Freya (0.3.2) and I tested the webkit4 ([LINK](http://valadoc.org/#!api=webkit2gtk-4.0/WebKit.WebView)), but do not work.
The code is:

```
public class Envideos : Gtk.Window {
    public Envideos () {
    this.title = "Envideos";
    this.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;
    this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);
    this.set_default_size (800, 600);

    WebKit.WebView thewebview2 = new WebKit.WebView();
    }
}

public static int main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);
    Envideos window = new Envideos ();
    window.show_all ();
    Gtk.main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, now I run valac and the resul is:

```
valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg webkit2gtk-4.0 testwebkit4.vala
testwebkit4.vala:8.17-8.50: warning: local variable `thewebview2' declared but never used
WebKit.WebView thewebview2 = new WebKit.WebView();
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/home/jockerfox/Projects-Eos/envideos/src/testwebkit4.vala.c:8:29: fatal error: webkit2/webkit2.h: File o directory non esistente 
#include <webkit2/webkit2.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
error: cc exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

Obviusly, forgotten the warning but concentrate to error.
Note that I have got the libwebkit2gtk-3.0-dev installed on my Freya.

Where I wrong ?

Comment: You are trying to compile with the v4 webkit2 package and you have installed v3 package.

Comment: Hi bitseater. Thanks to replay. The valadoc.org say webkit-1.0 package is deprecated. So we need use webkit2gtk-4.0. Maybe my Freya use the v3, how can update the package to v4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According with *Valadoc* , webkit2gtk-3.0 bindings are replaced in Vala by webkit2gtk-4.0 since version 0.25.2 .

In order to install **webkit2gtk-4.0** you can try in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webkit-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev
```

If you want to access the WebKit2 documentation, you must run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-doc
```

More info about webkit2gtk-4.0 at:

[WebKitGTK+ Project](http://webkitgtk.org/)

[WebKitGTK+ Valadoc reference](http://www.valadoc.org/#!wiki=webkit2gtk-4.0/index)